# If I go on the waiting list to buy a RPi, do I have to buy one? Can I add myself to both waiting lists?

Tags: purchasing

If I sign up for waiting lists at both Farnell and RS Components to try to get my RPi slightly sooner, will it cause any problems?

Am I committing to buy one when I go on the waiting list?

When are the waiting lists expected to be cleared?

Comment: We're trying to keep away from questions about RPi distribution. You're better off checking with the distributor and saving your hardware/software questions for us.

Comment: I asked a similar question a minute ago, and was pointed to [this meta question](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/20/99) by @jivings, where there seems to be consensus on the topic

Comment: See this question: [Are questions about ordering and shipping on-topic?](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/20/46).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my friends signed up to grab a Pi from both Farnell and RS, he received both without any problems. I'm not sure if this is *technically* allowed, but I doubt you'd have any grief - especially if you're registering interest now when the availability isn't anywhere near as scarce as it was a few months ago.

Comment: I did the same. They arrived a month apart.

Comment: One of the companies was useless, I forget which one it was

Comment: @Jivings RS only had a "register your interest" list for ages, hence why I went with Farnell.